# Tinder-like instagram integration feature

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I need some help with my app, I need to make a Tinder-like instagram integration feature, my app has a search engine like google maps but is created to find Senior Care Homes so a user has a profile and has his facilities associated, so I need that the user associate an instagram account for each facility he has in his profile, but i don't know how to handle this because every token that comes in the facebook login response expires in 60 days, so if I store that token in DB to every time another user visits a facility detail it will request FB API trying to get instagram photos but what if token has expired?, so if someone can help me with this I would really appreciate. Thanks.

I haven't tried anything because i don't really know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Not sure if there is any mechanism for “unlimited” access when it comes to the new Instagram API.

Comment: you just use a facebook page token with the new instagram api, so i would assume the same limitations apply. did you try with a page token, NOT a user token?

Comment: @luschn thanks for your comment, i read about page tokens but I don't really find a difference, both have the same refresh process. The only solution I find is that while the user session is active make some request periodically to keep the token alive.

Comment: page tokens can be valid forever under some circumstances, i believe. anyway, you need to use a page token for pages and instagram, and the instagram account needs to be a business account connected to a facebook page. just in case you do not know yet.

Comment: @luschn https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#authentication says you need to use user tokens for all requests, and even _“Note that Page tokens are not supported.”_ Also, the reference for the individual endpoints says user token everywhere as far as I can see.

Comment: interesting, i am using page tokens for the instagram api for a while now...

Comment: @luschn I could finally use never-expire tokens, with Page token, in Facebook Token Debugger it says: Expire: never. So i think it's done, thank you!

Comment: please create an answer with detailed information and accept it :)